# Woocommerce Emails not being sent

Tags: plugins, email

I would like to know the best way to debug email issues in woocommerce when the mails are not being sent for any account/Order related processes.

Thanks

Comment: Just use postmark (postmarkapp.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like your site is unable to send emails from the web server or your emails are being blocked by spam filters. Try setting up a free account at one of the two services I've linked to below and install their WordPress plugin and see if this fixes your email issues.

[Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/)

[Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/)

Comment: An answer should not rely on external pages. When these links vanish, your answer will become useless. Please add a solution for the question.